# Do we have an "m-dot" site?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, mobile, mobile-first-index

Attempting to follow

- [Mobile First Indexing](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-first-indexing)
- [Dynamic Serving / Separate URLs](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls)

I currently work for a company that dynamically serves content based on the user agent. However, it is not divided by subdomain such as:

- `example.com`
- `m.example.com`

Rather it is served as:

- `example.com`
- `example.com/mobile/`

Does this still qualify as an "m-dot" site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mobile site that uses **separate URLs**.  That is in the same category as m-dot sites, but your site doesn't use a mobile subdomain, it uses a mobile subdirectory.

From [Google's mobile SEO overview](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/), the three types of mobile designs are:

- Responsive Web Design
- Dynamic Serving
- Separate URLs

Having a `/mobile/` subdirectory puts your site in the "Separate URLs" category.   Because an m-dot website is also "Separate URLs", any m-dot advice is likely going to apply to your website as well.

The reason that Google calls the category "separate URLs" and says "sometimes known as m-dot" is because there are other ways to make separate URLs other than a `m.` mobile subdomain.  In your case you have a subdirectory.  It is possible to use URL parameters like `?mobile=true`.   You could use a different subdomain such as `phones.example.com` instead of `m.example.com`.  In any case, all the m-dot advice applies to you and I would recommend using the term "separate URLs site" rather than "m-dot site".